# upload csv file and save data in data base in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

How can i upload csv file and save data in to my mysql database.
according to id.in cakephp 3
i am unable to do that. can any one help me.
my controller
    public function import() {

```
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
        if($_FILES['file']['csv']){
            $filename = explode('.', $_FILES['file']['csv']);
            debug($filename);
            if($filename[1]=='csv'){
                $handle = fopen($_FILES['file']['csv'], "r");
                while ($data = fgetcsv($handle)){
                    $item1 = $data[0];
                  //  $item2 = $data[1];
                  //  $item3 = $data[2];
                  //  $item4 = $data[3];
                    $Applicants = $this->Applicants->patchEntity($Applicants, $item1);
                    $this->Applicants->save($Applicants);
                }
                fclose($handle);
            }
        }
    }
    $this->render(FALSE);
}
```

my view:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
        <?= $this->Form->create('Applicants',['type' => 'file','url' => ['controller'=>'Applicants','action' => 'import'],'class'=>'form-inline','role'=>'form',]) ?>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="csv"> CSV </label>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('csv', ['type'=>'file','class' => 'form-control', 'label' => false, 'placeholder' => 'csv upload',]); ?>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"> Upload </button>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear what do you want to do in the controller do you want to update the existing records or save new data. If you want to update then only you need to use patchEntity.

The patchEntity should have a database entity fetched where in you can change or update the data as per your need, so in case if your first column contains the id of the Applications table then below code can work and in $data you can write whatever fields you want to update or add

**So you can use the below code block instead**

```
public function import() {
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
        if($_FILES['file']['csv']){
            $filename = explode('.', $_FILES['file']['csv']);
            debug($filename);
            if($filename[1]=='csv'){

                $handle = fopen($_FILES['file']['csv'], "r");
                while ($data = fgetcsv($handle)){
                    $item1 = $data[0];

                    $data = array(
                        'fieldName' => $item1
                    );
                  //  $item2 = $data[1];
                  //  $item3 = $data[2];
                  //  $item4 = $data[3];
                    $Applicant = $this->Applicants->newEntity($data);
                    $this->Applicants->save($Applicant);
                }
                fclose($handle);
            }
        }
    }
    $this->render(FALSE);
}
```

If you have more specific code/requirement then please share, so that I can help you out accordingly.

Comment: i want to upload csv file and insert data according id in my database.but i am unable to do that in cakephp 3

Comment: do you want to insert the data row by row or all at once if you want to save the data row by row then you can use newEntity instead of patch Entity in the while loop itself in the above code.

Comment: please check my edit, this should work now as intended

Comment: @Md.Shahjalal if it serves the purpose, then please accept my answer.

Comment: your answer help me.to find the solution at last i can do it thanks Rohit

Comment: Alright thanks for that, had your question been more specific I would have answered it better, anyways please select my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Solution to upload csv file and save database
public function import($id = NULL) {

```
    $data = $this->request->data['csv'];
    $file = $data['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

        if($row[0] == 'id') {
            continue;
        }

        $Applicants = $this->Applicants->get($row[0]);
        $columns = [
            'written_mark' => $row[1],
            'written_comments' => $row[2],
            'viva_mark' => $row[3],
            'viva_comments' => $row[4]
        ];
        $Applicant = $this->Applicants->patchEntity($Applicants, $columns);
        $this->Applicants->save($Applicant);
    }

    fclose($handle);
    $this->set('title','Upload Student CSV File Input Number and others');
    return $this->redirect($this->referer());
}
```